# z-index не применяется

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

Не понимаю в чем ошибка и почему горизонтальная линия перекрывает круглую иконку, имея z-index: -1.

Вот результат!

[image: result]

HTML:

```
<ol class="stage-list list-unstyled">
    <li class="stage-list__item">
        <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">1</a>
        <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Checkout</span>  
    </li>
    <li class="stage-list__item current">
        <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">2</a>
        <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Confirmation</span>  
    </li>
    <li class="stage-list__item">
        <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">4</a>
        <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Payment</span>   
    </li>
</ol>
```

SCSS:

```
.stage-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;

    &__item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__item:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 75px;
    }

    &__link {
        position: relative;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;

        color: #000;
        border: 3px solid #00bfa5;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    &__item:not(:last-child) .stage-list__link:after {
        content: '';

        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 100%;

        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        height: 3px;

        background-color: #00bfa5;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допишите `background: #fff;` для `.stage-list__link`:

```css
.stage-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.stage-list__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.stage-list__item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.stage-list__link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #000;
  border: 3px solid #00bfa5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.stage-list__item:not(:last-child) .stage-list__link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ol class="stage-list list-unstyled">
  <li class="stage-list__item">
    <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">1</a>
    <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Checkout</span>
  </li>
  <li class="stage-list__item current">
    <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">2</a>
    <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Confirmation</span>
  </li>
  <li class="stage-list__item">
    <a class="stage-list__link" href="#">4</a>
    <span class="stage-list__title text-uppercase">Payment</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Там не *#FFF*. Скорее *#F4F4F4*. Судя по фону на картинке

Comment: @Yuri я ориентировался на код, а не на картинку

Comment: @Cheg нужно учитывать все входные данные :)